# Seeking tools for regionalization/redistricting?

Tags: software-recommendations, clustering, redistricting, regionalization

I am looking for tools for regionalization / districting in GIS.

So far I have been able to identify

- [Districting](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/districting/index.html) ArcGIS extension (now also [online](http://www.esri.com/software/redistricting/index.html))
- [REDCAP](http://www.spatialdatamining.org/software/redcap) (currently limited to 50k input polygons)
- [iRedistrict](http://www.spatialdatamining.org/iRedistrict) (not yet released)
- [R method](http://dsparks.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/k-means-redistricting/)

Is there anything else available out there? Especially something that will have no problems in dealing with quite large dataset [~ 1.3 million polygons]?

Answer (score 6):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

Follow-up with some other non-commercial web apps people have been developing:

- Florida is rolling their own MyDistrictBuilder web ap: http://www.floridaredistricting.org/ (app may be at http://floridaredistricting.cloudapp.net/MyDistrictBuilder.aspx, website claims they'll have public testing in March)
- Profs. Altman and McDonald are developing the open-source DistrictBuilder: http://www.publicmapping.org/ (demo at https://demo.publicmapping.org/)
- Something else from the Fuzzy Tolerance blog: http://fuzzytolerance.info/code/lightweight-redistricting-with-openlayers-part-ii/ (demo here: http://maps.co.mecklenburg.nc.us/redistricting/)

The open software TerraView (http://www.dpi.inpe.br/terraview_eng/index.php) has a regionalization method called SKATER. It's description can be found here:

Assunção, Renato M., *et al.* "Efficient regionalization techniques for socio‐economic geographical units using minimum spanning trees." International Journal of Geographical Information Science 20.7 (2006): 797-811. Available at: http://www.dpi.inpe.br/gilberto/papers/assuncao_neves_camara_ijgis.pdf

The same method is also available in Python package `regionskate` ([pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regionskate/1.0.0), [github](https://github.com/ljwolf/regionskate)).

Python's [PySAL](http://pysal.github.io/) library supports [regionalization](http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/v1.11.0/users/tutorials/region.html). It uses the max-p [algorithm](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9787.2011.00743.x/abstract) that does not force the user to specify a priori the number of regions (which is often the case in other methods).

David Martin's (University of Southampton) [AZTool](https://www.geodata.soton.ac.uk/software/AZTool/) is another option. Software has a solid methodology behind it and I presume it can handle large datasets since it has been used:

```
... by the Office for National Statistics (ONS) to create the 2001 Census output geographies for England and Wales
```

NCRM has some online learning [resources](https://www.ncrm.ac.uk/resources/online/automated_zone_design/) that cover the topic.