# Divide polygon based on points for even distribution

Tags: polygon, point, point-in-polygon

If I have a point layer, how can I create a polygon that includes all of the points and divide that polygon into *n* sections in which each section contains an equal number of points? Preferably in QGIS, but other systems are acceptable.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you have an odd number of points?

Comment: Also when you say equal number are you looking for a maximum or minimum? For example say you have 10 points do you want 2 sections of 5 or 5 sections of 2?

Comment: A minor variation of the solutions offered at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31236 will solve this problem, too. In that question the points are aggregated into rectangles. The union of those rectangles will form the polygon you want.