# Regionalization with variable weights

Tags: regionalization

I am looking for regionalization software, that is, I want to cluster regions based on multivariate attribute data with the added constraint of spatial contiguity.

I have found various software for doing this including those listed on [another GIS.se question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3189/seeking-tools-for-regionalization-redistricting/6452#6452)

All so far seem to standardize data before clustering, so data measured in different units are treated equally. None so far, however, offer the ability to weight variables. So for example if I determine that population density is twice as important as house price in determining regions, I would like to be able to specify this to the algorithm.

Is there some regionalization software out there that allows variable weighting?